# How to copy missing line in a *.f25 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I want to copy missing lines of a *.f25 file. *.f25 files are a kind of textfile.
In the following there is an example of the file. There are recordings of the device. There are a line 5303. After this line there should be always a record of three beats. Sometimes the second and third beat is not recored. It **SHOULD ALWAYS** be 3 beats, otherwise the program does not start. And for this reason I want to find the missing lines and copy the line above and rename to 2 or 3.

I tried it with the following code, but I'm new in Pyhton and have really no clue.

```
filename =   'C:\xxx\xx\Helga\B22 20220829 km0,0-7,8 LJ.F25'      
with open(filename,'r') as infile:
  inlines=infile.readlines()
    for line in inlines:
        if line.find(' 3, ') !=-1:
            line.copy(' 2, ')
            print('done')
```

```
5001,25.20,1,40, 3, 1,"FwdWin          ",9,03,"043927D019224AA4A472BFE970F9E57"
5002,"25SIN   ","8002-460","CP15-754"
5003,"Dynatest","Asphalt-","L93 2022","F25"
5010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,"MDB","SI","kilometers"
5011,0,1,2022,07,27,15,28,0,"Non",000
5200,"7159    ",2,1.000, 64.7,  0.01,  2.990
5201,"8051    ",5,1.000,1.011
5202,"8052    ",5,1.000,0.985
5203,"8053    ",5,1.000,1.012
5204,"8054    ",5,1.000,1.032
5205,"8055    ",5,1.000,0.967
5206,"8056    ",5,1.000,1.019
5207,"8057    ",5,1.000,0.997
5208,"8058    ",5,1.000,0.994
5209,"8059    ",5,1.000,0.991
5210,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5211,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5212,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5213,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5214,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5215,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5216,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5217,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5218,"NA      ",0,0.000,0.000
5020,   150,     0,   200,   300,   450,   600,   900,  1200,  1500,  1800,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    
5021,   300,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    ,N0    
5022,1,   0,   0,   50,  100,  200,  390,
5023,1,3,0,   0.051,  11.400,   0.051,  -0.147,   0.000,1,1
5024,1,0,0,1,3,3,     5, 2.0,     2, 2.0,1,1,0,  60
5029,      58,     165,    4344,   16588
5030,"Dynatest                        "
5031
5032,"","","11,4","0"
5301,0,1,3,3,   0.051,1,1,        ,2022,07,27,15,28
5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
5303,0,N0   , 31.7, 23.2
5041,"                "
5042,"                "
5043,"                "
5044,"                "
5301,0,1,3,3,  11.400,1,1,        ,2022,07,27,14,03
5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
**5303,0,N0   , 32.5, 25.3
   1,   693, 336.0, 233.2, 177.2, 117.5,  85.8,  59.3,  50.4,  42.5,  35.6
   2,   691, 318.9, 223.0, 170.4, 114.5,  84.5,  59.7,  50.7,  43.0,  35.9**
5301,0,1,3,3,  11.201,1,1,        ,2022,07,27,14,08
5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
5303,0,N0   , 33.8, 26.1
   1,   691, 377.2, 268.2, 200.5, 132.2,  91.1,  49.8,  31.7,  21.6,  15.4
   2,   693, 349.3, 249.8, 188.3, 126.3,  89.4,  51.0,  33.2,  22.9,  16.8
   3,   693, 344.9, 247.3, 186.5, 125.5,  89.2,  51.0,  33.3,  22.9,  16.9
5301,0,1,3,3,  11.000,1,1,        ,2022,07,27,14,09
5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
**5303,0,N0   , 31.7, 26.4
   1,   681, 431.2, 336.2, 277.4, 206.4, 155.6,  96.0,  68.1,  51.3,  39.4
   2,   686, 409.8, 320.6, 266.5, 200.0, 153.4,  97.5,  70.3,  53.3,  41.7**
```

I want to find the missing lines and copy the line above and rename to 2 or 3.
Help is very appreciated!

Comment: How do you know if the lines are missing, and copy the live above what, exactly? Update your question with your desired output/file.

Comment: Would you please me and give some feedback on the answer I've posted? Tia.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it does not joining the missing lines, because, it didn't find it and there is also a syntax error in the last line.

Comment: Dear Helga F., my apologies for the delayed reply, I haven't received a notification. ፨ ፨ ፨ ፨ Below I have augmented my post with the transcript of a terminal session where I check that my code works without raising a syntax error and appends copies of the preceding line just as you have requested. ፨ ፨ ፨ ፨ If you need help running my code, please add a comment **below my post**, so that I'll receive a prompt notification.

Answer (score 1):

A bit complicated.

Slurp all the data in a list, splitting the text on newlines.

Loop on the list, keeping track of the index.

If a line is a "`5303`" fetch at most 3 lines in a list named `lines`, check for EoF, check that we have at least an "interesting" line, strip "uninteresting" lines from the the end of `lines`, count the number of lines in `lines` and possibly join (using `"\n"`) to the last line in `lines` one or two copies of itself, with a number replaced by a different one.

When all lines have been read, print the output joining with a `"\n"` the individual lines.

```
from sys import stdout

# for you it's
# data = open('...').read().splitlines()
data = '''\
5001,25.20,1,40, 3, 1,"FwdWin          ",9,03,"043927D019224AA4A472BFE970F9E57"
5002,"25SIN   ","8002-460","CP15-754"
...
5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
5303,0,N0   , 31.7, 26.4
   1,   681, 431.2, 336.2, 277.4, 206.4, 155.6,  96.0,  68.1,  51.3,  39.4
   2,   686, 409.8, 320.6, 266.5, 200.0, 153.4,  97.5,  70.3,  53.3,  41.7
'''.splitlines()

regular = lambda s: s[0]!=" "
add_3 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('2','3',1)))
add23 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('1','2',1),
                             s.replace('1','3',1)))

for n, line in enumerate(data):
    if line[:9] != "5303,0,N0": continue
    # we have next 0, 1, 2 or 3 lines starting with "   [123]"
    lines = data[n+1:n+4]
    if len(lines) == 0 : continue # End of Data
    if regular(lines[0]) : continue
    # assertion: at least the first line in lines is non-regular
    # strip regular lines (at most 2) from the end of "lines"
    for _ in (1,2):
        if regular(lines[-1]): lines = lines[:-1]
    if len(lines) == 3 : continue
    if len(lines) == 2 : data[n+2] = add_3(data[n+2])
    if len(lines) == 1 : data[n+1] = add23(data[n+1])

# for you it's
# print('\n'.join(data), file=open("...", "w"))
print('\n'.join(data), file=stdout)
# note that the extra lines were "joined" using '\n' as well
```

---

### Addendum

---

Because

- the OP [has written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75787988/how-to-copy-missing-line-in-a-f25-file/75790237#comment133749316_75787988) *"Unfortunately it does not joining the missing lines, because, it didn't find it and there is also a syntax error in the last line."* , and
- I test my solution before posting (and in this case, in a thoroughly manner),

I do feel entitled to post below the transcript of a terminal session where I check that my code really does what it is supposed to do.

If the OP wants some help for using correctly my code, they are welcome.

---

```
12:49 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ cat f25.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import stdin
regular = lambda s: s[0]!=" "
add_3 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('2','3',1)))
add23 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('1','2',1),
                             s.replace('1','3',1)))
data = stdin.read().splitlines()
for n, line in enumerate(data):
    if line[:9] != "5303,0,N0": continue
    # we have next 0, 1, 2 or 3 lines starting with "   [123]"
    lines = data[n+1:n+4]
    if len(lines) == 0 : continue # End of Data
    if regular(lines[0]) : continue
    # assertion: at least the first line in lines is non-regular
    # strip regular lines (at most 2) from the end of "lines"
    for _ in (1,2):
        if regular(lines[-1]): lines = lines[:-1]
    if len(lines) == 3 : continue
    if len(lines) == 2 : data[n+2] = add_3(data[n+2])
    if len(lines) == 1 : data[n+1] = add23(data[n+1])
print('\n'.join(data))
12:49 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ ./f25.py < input.f25 > output.f25
12:49 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ cat f25.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import stdin
regular = lambda s: s[0]!=" "
add_3 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('2','3',1)))
add23 = lambda s: '\n'.join((s, s.replace('1','2',1),
                             s.replace('1','3',1)))
data = stdin.read().splitlines()
for n, line in enumerate(data):
    if line[:9] != "5303,0,N0": continue
    # we have next 0, 1, 2 or 3 lines starting with "   [123]"
    lines = data[n+1:n+4]
    if len(lines) == 0 : continue # End of Data
    if regular(lines[0]) : continue
    # assertion: at least the first line in lines is non-regular
    # strip regular lines (at most 2) from the end of "lines"
    for _ in (1,2):
        if regular(lines[-1]): lines = lines[:-1]
    if len(lines) == 3 : continue
    if len(lines) == 2 : data[n+2] = add_3(data[n+2])
    if len(lines) == 1 : data[n+1] = add23(data[n+1])
print('\n'.join(data))
12:50 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ chmod +x f25.py
12:50 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ ./f25.py < input.f25 > output.f25
12:50 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $ diff -c input.f25 output.f25 
*** input.f25   2023-03-27 12:40:39.432751456 +0200
--- output.f25  2023-03-27 12:50:56.250469361 +0200
***************
*** 43,48 ****
--- 43,49 ----
  5303,0,N0   , 32.5, 25.3
     1,   693, 336.0, 233.2, 177.2, 117.5,  85.8,  59.3,  50.4,  42.5,  35.6
     2,   691, 318.9, 223.0, 170.4, 114.5,  84.5,  59.7,  50.7,  43.0,  35.9
+    3,   691, 318.9, 223.0, 170.4, 114.5,  84.5,  59.7,  50.7,  43.0,  35.9
  5301,0,1,3,3,  11.201,1,1,        ,2022,07,27,14,08
  5302,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,"          "
  5303,0,N0   , 33.8, 26.1
***************
*** 54,56 ****
--- 55,58 ----
  5303,0,N0   , 31.7, 26.4
     1,   681, 431.2, 336.2, 277.4, 206.4, 155.6,  96.0,  68.1,  51.3,  39.4
     2,   686, 409.8, 320.6, 266.5, 200.0, 153.4,  97.5,  70.3,  53.3,  41.7
+    3,   686, 409.8, 320.6, 266.5, 200.0, 153.4,  97.5,  70.3,  53.3,  41.7
12:51 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/Code $
```

Comment: Dear gboffi! Thank you so much for your help. The reason for the syntax error was the wrong python version. I had installed mutiple versions. My fault. 
Unfortunatley, it does not find the missing lines. Idk why. Maybe a sample file would help? It was only a short version of the total record. Kind regard H.

Comment: @HelgaF — I wrote the script according to your problem description, I've checked it against the data you provided, and it works (as shown in my answer). The only idea I have, maybe the line `if line[:9] != "5303,0,N0": continue` is too strict, and you can have better results with  `if line[:5] != "5303,": continue`, or maybe using a regexp to match `"5303"` in a less strict context...

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH! Now it works perfectly! :) And sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @HelgaF. Very happy that you succeeded 